# Padding in theorem environment with thmtools

Tags: theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I'm using thmtools to make shaded theorems, but there is no padding around the theorem body and that makes it ugly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\colorlet{LightGray}{White!90!Periwinkle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    name=Theorem,
    shaded={bgcolor=LightGray},
]{thmsty}
\declaretheorem[style=thmsty]{thm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle) is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two legs (the two sides that meet at a right angle).
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: thm]

I'd like to add padding all around the theorem. I read `thmtools` documentation but didn't find a way to do it. I don't mind if the shaded box gets larger than `\textwidth`.

Comment: Use `tcolorbox` and it's `tcbtheorem` features, that provides much nicer boxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the `tcolorboxenvironment` wrapper style for `thm`, providing nicer boxes (in my point of view), with effectively one line of code!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\colorlet{LightGray}{White!90!Periwinkle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    name=Theorem,
]{thmsty}
\declaretheorem[style=thmsty]{thm}

\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{enhanced jigsaw,colback=LightGray,drop shadow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle) is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two legs (the two sides that meet at a right angle).
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed `tcolorbox` is very easy to use with the `\tcolorboxenvironment` command. I didn't know such a command existed. I'm choosing this answer because it's the easiest one to customize.

Comment: @rubik: You're welcome -- please note that `tcolorbox` provides a lot of specialized `theorem` environments as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `mdframed` options in the theorem style allows one to set borders of specified size, here set to 6 or 8pt, depending.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\colorlet{LightGray}{White!90!Periwinkle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    name=Theorem,
    mdframed={
  skipabove=8pt,
  skipbelow=6pt,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor={LightGray},
  innerleftmargin=8pt,
  innerrightmargin=8pt}
]{thmsty}
\declaretheorem[style=thmsty]{thm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{thm}
        In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle) is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two legs (the two sides that meet at a right angle).
    \end{thm}

    In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle) is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two legs (the two sides that meet at a right angle).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, somehow I had missed the `mdframed` option!